# .htaccess RewriteRule for remapping folder in CodeIgniter doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, remap

I want users to see what's in /index.php?events/ when they type /prefiltered/. So, I don't want their browsers to display /index.php?events/. I think it's called **remapping**.

I'm using CodeIgniter, working in local and yes, I've activated mod_rewrite in my apache server.

I'm trying this with no positive results:

```
# CodeIngniter Configuration
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# What I want to get to work
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^prefiltered/? /index.php?events/ [NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Routing. You need to do it in /application/routes.php file. 
Htaccess file should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And in routes.php add following line:

```
$route['events'] = "prefiltered";
```

Hope it helps.